# Enum-like derived class

Tags: c++

I currently have a code as follows:

```cpp
enum class Mode {
    Foo,
    Bar
};

void function(int a, Mode mode);
```

I want to drastically extend the 'mode'. In particular, I want to allow an option argument that accepts an `Option`-class and one of several `enum`(-like) objects. Such that the user could do either of the following:

```cpp
function(a, Mode::Foo);
function(a, Direction::Forward);
function(a, Option(...));
```

Is this possible with a single overload of `function`? However, such that `function` only accepts an `Option` object and `Mode::Foo`, `Mode::Bar`, `Direction::Forward`, `Direction::Backward` (and not more than that, with a generic template, as it would destroy my overload resolution).

---

I was thinking along the lines of having classes deriving from `Option`, and having

```cpp
void function(int a, const Option& option);
```

But I don't know how to do this without the user needing to add parentheses for `Mode` and `Direction`:

```cpp
function(a, Mode::Foo());
function(a, Direction::Forward());
function(a, Option(...));
```

which I don't want to maintain backward compatibility.

Comment: It would be possible to use a template function with SFINAE, or, better yet, define a C++20 constraint that's satisfied by those condition, and define a template that takes this constraint as its 2nd parameter.

Comment: You can create an empty struct and accept this type, then you only have to define the objects deriving from that struct. It's no longer an enum, so you lose some features, but if you just need it as a meaningful empty "object" then that's fine.

That or SFINAE / C++20 concepts

Comment: Thanks you for your reply @SamVarshavchik ! Could I, using SFINAE, test from the `enum`s as well? (Note: this is an HPC project, so I don't want to go higher than C++14 for the moment, to avoid other headaches)

Comment: Only if the enums are passed as template parameters, and not as variables. You cannot restrict, at compile time, values that are only known at runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Geoffroy ! I think I almost get what you mean ;) Do you mean that `Mode::Foo` is a struct deriving from `Option` (itself being empty)?

Comment: @TomdeGeus `Mode` is a struct deriving from `Option`, and `Foo` (or `Mode::Foo`) is an instance of `Mode`

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple objects acting as flags for that, although you'll lose some advantage of the `enum` (even if you can work around that too):

```cpp
struct Option{};
struct Mode
{
  Mode Foo;
}
```

Place this line in a C++ file, it should be in only ONE translation unit

```cpp
Mode Mode::Foo{};
```

Then you can use simple overloading:

```cpp
void function(const Option& opt);
```

You can of course put private/protected constructors to prevent the creation of others objects outside the class definition.

Another solution would be to use templates, with SFINAE or C++20 constraints/concepts to restrict what you allow as a parameter.